# What does "Provides Equity" mean on the Jobs offers?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm not a native English speaker nor someone in the job world yet so maybe it's a silly question, but what does it mean?

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/54648/50440

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Usually means the company offers shares in the company in the form of stock options or stocks as part of compensation.

Comment: So it's a good or bad thing? Usuallym it's your salary+stock or part of the salary as stock?

Comment: @Aimnox It's not good or bad in and of itself.  It's different.  Some people will like it, some won't.  And of course the specifics will matter a lot as well.

Comment: @Aimnox - there is no one correct way to understand it. Every company does different things. What one usually sees - you have your salary - the stocks are just extra (and only granted after a set time of working at a company).